# Google Contacts API - Selecting Event Data

Tags: php, xml, api, google-api

I am trying to obtain information based on the google contacts "events" (ie: anniversary's etct) "they seem to reference them as 'events'".

So none-the-less. I have been able to obtain some of the data in a shortened cleaned up format.
This is the XML that I am working with to obtain this information.

[13] => Zend_Gdat

```
a_App_Extension_Element Object
        (
            [_rootElement:protected] => event
            [_extensionElements:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Zend_Gdata_App_Extension_Element Object (
                            [_rootElement:protected] => when
                            [_extensionAttributes:protected] => Array (
                                    [startTime] => Array (
                                            [namespaceUri] => 
                                            [name] => startTime
                                            [value] => 2009-05-09))
                            [_text:protected] => 
                        )
                )

            [_extensionAttributes:protected] => Array (
                    [rel] => Array (
                            [namespaceUri] => 
                            [name] => rel
                            [value] => anniversary ))
            [_text:protected] => 
        )
```

So what I have done to obtain the TYPE of EVENT I use this code so far.

```
//    Get All Events
foreach ($xml->event as $e) {                       
    if($e['rel'] == "anniversary") {
        // echo "This is true, this is anniversary";
    }
}
```

And to Obtain the actual Event VALUE (the start Time). I THOUGHT I would use something like this running inside the for each loop.

```
foreach ($xml->event as $e) {                       
    echo $e->when['startTime'];
}
```

But this just echo's NULL.
I have tried many variations and can't seem to get it, although I'm not sure if it's just due to my over-tiredness. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution.

```
//    Get All Events
foreach ($xml->event as $e) {
    $defaults = $e->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'); 

    if($e['rel'] == "anniversary") {
        $obj->anniversary = (string) $defaults->when->attributes()->startTime;
    }
}
```